# Windows CryptoAPI symmetric encoding/decoding block that already aligning

Tags: c++, aes, padding, cryptoapi, ecb

I need migrating from OpenSSL to MS CryptoAPI.

When I use OpenSSL, I got N-bytes (already aligned - for example, let say the data length = 32bytes) of data and encode/decode it from one buffer to another. All works fine.

Now I must "use CryptoAPI!".
So I write something like:

```
    // Import AES key
    if(!CryptImportKey(m_hProvider, (CONST BYTE*)&aeskey, structsize, NULL, 0, &m_hAesKey ) ) {
        throw WinAESException("SetKey: Import key failed");
    }

    // Set Mode
    DWORD dwMode = CRYPT_MODE_ECB; //I can also use CRYPT_MODE_CBC with set of IV but let simple the code;
    if(!CryptSetKeyParam(m_hAesKey, KP_MODE, (BYTE*)&dwMode, 0)) {
        throw WinAESException("SetKey: Set ECB mode failed");
    }
```

It's works ok,
and now I try to encode the data

```
    DWORD d = (DWORD)psize;
    result = CryptEncrypt( m_hAesKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, buffer, &d, (DWORD)bsize );
```

And what I see? The encoded part of data is larger than source.
I understand that the CryptEncrypt function somehow padded already padding data?

Is it possible, anyhow, to get the codded result the same size as it was plain data?

I do not use not-aligned block, I want, when I encrypt 32bytes, to get exactly 32bytes, not 48...

When I test expected size

```
    DWORD d = 16;
    result = CryptEncrypt( m_hAesKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, 0, &d, (DWORD)bsize );  //need 32

    d = 32;
    result = CryptEncrypt( m_hAesKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, 0, &d, (DWORD)bsize );  //need 48 

    d = 48;
    result = CryptEncrypt( m_hAesKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, 0, &d, (DWORD)bsize );   //need 64

    d = 64;
    result = CryptEncrypt( m_hAesKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, 0, &d, (DWORD)bsize );  //need 80
```

WTHF I do wrong? 
P.S. If I truncate the encrypted result to desired size and then try to decrypt it, decryption done with returned expected error code, but the data decrypted correctly.  but this hack is not for me...

Comment: Data is padded as AES only encrypts whole blocks.  AES assumes that when decrypting that the last encrypted data-block has padding.  This means that if the last data-block to be encrypted is the same size as the AES-block size a padding block must be added.  If this padding is not added AES has no way to determine if the last block contains padding or not.

Comment: When I use OpenSSL, or LibTomCrypt  I'm able to switch off padding for AES ECB/CBC. In MS cryptoAPI it seems no such option... I did not see "NO_PADDING" flag: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380272(v=vs.85).aspx (see KP_PADDING value)

Comment: This is not your problem, but ECB is a *horrible* mode.  *Even* if your message is always less than one block, it leaks the fact that you sent the same message twice.  I suspect that CAPI just doesn't support what you want.  All is not lost however: Use BCryptEncrypt (which is a CNG API).  It *does* support no padding of whole block messages.

Comment: Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not encode and decode - it's encrypt and decrypt.

Microsoft probably adds PKCS5_PADDING by default - there is no such option as NO_PADDING.
It's pretty strange, especially for ECB mode but it explains why CryptEncrypt returns extended buffer size - it adds one more block for padding.

On the other hand your "hack" with bFinal == FALSE in the answer above is actually fine, because ECB mode doesn't require any finalization process.

If you are going go use other crypt modes then you should always Encrypt with bFinal == TRUE.

Also if you want to do it right you should encrypt in two steps:

```
DWORD dwEncryptedDataLen = dwRealDataLen; 
result = CryptEncrypt(m_hAesKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, &dwEncryptedDataLen, 0);
...
pbData = (BYTE*)malloc(dwEncryptedDataLen);
memcpy(pbData, pbRealData, dwRealDataLen);
...
result = CryptEncrypt(m_hAesKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, pbData, &dwRealDataLen, dwEncryptedDataLen);
...
```

Don't forget to check the result value of Crypt functions.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that I find the temporary solution.
When I need to encrypt/decrypt the entire block - all I need is to lie the function - "it is not the last/the only block":
So type not:

```
result = CryptEncrypt( m_hAesKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, buffer, &d, (DWORD)bsize );
```

but:

```
result = CryptEncrypt( m_hAesKey, NULL, FALSE, 0, buffer, &d, (DWORD)bsize );
```

Now it works. And hope they do not change concept of padding data at the end of last piece to start add alignment at the begining of block...

Comment: Fixes like this are just a disaster waiting to happen. You need to fully understand the problem and the solution. You need to study padding and why it is necessary, see [Padding (cryptography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) and in particular PKCS#7 padding. 

If the input data is not always a multiple of the block size then padding must be added to the input data; specify padding, PKCS#75 is the preferred padding for AES.

Comment: As I write at the very top - my data is always already aligned and cannot be other.

Comment: If padding is used it must be applied on every message even if the input data is already an exact multiple of the block size in which case a full block of padding is added. Consider, just looking at the decrypted data how would you tell if there is padding if the last byte was 0x01, so it must always be added. The only exception is that padding is not necessary and not specified if the data is **always** an exact multiple of the block size.

Comment: :) It is not the problem. I do not want and do not want to use padding at all.  If I got a slot of exactly 32bytes, and all 32 bytes must be encoded (transferred to somewhere) and than decoded - why I need to expand the slot to store additional garbage? And how to process if exists hardware size limitation?

Comment: As I stated: padding is not necessary and not specified if the data is **always** an exact multiple of the block size. Then do not specify padding. Note, padding may be the default for CryptoAPI and you may have to specify no padding: `PaddingMode.None`. Uou need to use the same padding mode on **every** call.

Comment: Then write the right answer - where I can set "PaddingMode.None" -  I did not find that place. bthw - I use c++ from Visual Studio 2010